# Не могу спозиционировать Rectangle на весь экран в QML

Tags: qt, qml, позиционирование, экран, окно

Делаю я заготовку виджета. Нужно, чтобы когда он виден, при клике НЕ на его область, чтобы виджет скрывался.

Я делаю так:

```
Window {
    id: picker

    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: sdStorageListWidget
        visible: true

        // Рабочая область посередине экрана, в ней будет список sdStorageListView
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        // Прямоугольник на весь экран, при нажатии на который виджет скрывается
        // Он нужен, чтобы виджет скрывался всегда при клике НЕ на область списка
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: picker.contentItem
            color: "yellow"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    sdStorageListWidget.visible=false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Область списка
        Rectangle {
            id: sdStorageListView
            anchors.fill: sdStorageListWidget
            color: "lightblue"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Click on sdStorageListView");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На на строке определения желтого Rectangle появляется ошибка:

```
QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.
```

Что-то я не пойму, вроде бы всегда можно было позиционироваться относительно любых элементов, которые ближе к корню по иерархии вложения. А тут почему-то говорится что можно позиционироваться только относительно родителя или элементов того же уровня.

Другими словами, желтый прямоугольник можно позиционировать относительно parent, но невозможно относительно parent.parent (оно же picker.contentItem). То есть относительно границ окна не спозиционируешься. Что за бред?

Comment: Никакого бреда, якорное позиционирование работает только с прямым родителем и «братьями»

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то необходимо вместо

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: picker.contentItem
    color: "yellow"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            sdStorageListWidget.visible=false;
        }
    }
}
```

разместить MouseArea на родительское окно Window id: picker и отбработать сигнал onClicked: пример ниже

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: picker

    visible: true

    width: 640
    height: 480

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            sdStorageListWidget.visible=false
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: sdStorageListWidget
        visible: true

        // Рабочая область посередине экрана, в ней будет список sdStorageListView
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        // Область списка
        Rectangle {
            id: sdStorageListView
            anchors.fill: sdStorageListWidget
            color: "lightblue"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Click on sdStorageListView");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```